# StaticLiveServerTestCase not logging in

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-testing, django-tests

I'm new to python. I'm trying to use `StaticLiveServerTestCase` with Python to login to the Django admin portal. I'm using the below code. Running the below code launches the admin portal but I'm unable to login with my credentials. Please let me know if I'm missing something. Thanks!

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

class MySeleniumTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    port = 0 
    host = <<my host>>
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/login/'))
        username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
        username_input.send_keys('myuser')
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys('secret')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Log in"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using create_superuser method in setUp resolved the issue. Below code resolves it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from django.test import Client
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
import time
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

#from apps.digital.models import User


class MyTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    port = 0
    host = 'my host'

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyTests, self).setUp()
        self.selenium = WebDriver()
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='test', password='Test1234', email='test@test.com', is_active=True)
        self.user.save()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.quit()
        super(MyTests, self).tearDown()

    def test_login(self):
        self.user = authenticate(username='test', password='Test1234')
        if self.user is not None:  # prints Backend login failed
            self.user = User.objects.get(username='test')
            print(self.user.username)  # prints test
            print(self.user.password)  # prints Test1234
            self.login = self.client.login(username='test', password='Test1234')
            self.assertEqual(self.login, True)
            print("Backend login successful")

            self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/admin/'))
            username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
            username_input.send_keys(self.user.username)
            password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
            password_input.send_keys('Test1234')
            self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Log in"]').click()
            time.sleep(1)

        else:
            print("Backend login failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a user in the test database. In [the example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase), it uses a fixture `'user-data.json'`.

Another option would be to create the user in `setUp` function.

```
class MySeleniumTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Set up data for the whole TestCase
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='username', password='password')
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, much appreciated. I tried to incorporate this and I see I can still NOT login.

class MyTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    port = 0
    host = 'my shost'

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyTests, self).setUp()
        self.selenium = WebDriver()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='Test@123')


    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.quit()
        super(MyTests, self).tearDown()

    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/admin/'))
        <login steps>

Comment: Please don’t post code in the comments, it’s impossible to read.

Comment: Sure. I just posted my updated code as a comment, can you please review whenever you got sometime?

Comment: Using create_superuser method in the setUp resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. `StaticLiveServerTestCase` is based on `TransactionTestCase`, so you can’t use `setUpTestData` which is from Django’s `TestCase`.